# MySQL set value using text and another field

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Okay, not quite sure how to explain it but I'll try my best...

I want to run a MySQL query to set names to 'Unmanaged Team [id]'
My thoughts were initially to use the following (but it doesn't work as hoped).

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `field`='Unmanaged Team'+`id`");
```

I've tried some variations of that, but I can't quite seems to figure it out, and I don't want to do them one by one, as that would just use far too many queries for something I'm sure can be done in 1.

Many thanks for taking some time to help me out :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
update `table` set `field` = concat('Unmanaged Team', id);
```

---

[`concat_ws`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) (concat with separator) is also useful if you want whitespace (or some other separator).

Comment: Ah thanks! I've never used that function before in MySQL, will remember that for the future.... thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 SET field =  CONCAT('something ',somefield)
```

Comment: remember that inside one CONCAT you can pass as many arguments you want. i.e.  concat('astring',name,'1234',password,'aaaa', .... )